# Bokeh log axis formatting as decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

For example I want to plot an axis in python using Bokeh with a log axis, but the label is in scientific notation (10^2) and I want to to be in integer notation (100). Example code and output below.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

x = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 80)
p = figure(title="log axis example", y_axis_type="log",
       x_range=(0, 5), y_range=(0.001, 10**22),
       background_fill_color="#fafafa")
p.line(x, x**2, legend="y=x**2")

show(p)
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `printfTickFormatter` to specify how much decimals a tick should have. More info on formatters:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import PrintfTickFormatter

x = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 80)
p = figure(title="log axis example", y_axis_type="log",
       x_range=(min(x)-0.1, max(x)+0.1), y_range=(min(x**2), max(x**2)),
       background_fill_color="#fafafa")
p.line(x, x**2, legend="y=x**2")
p.yaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%5f")

show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked into the LogTickFormatter and couldn't find any solutions, but this worked great!